# combine rotation and translation with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

i'm using Three.js (without shaders, only with existing objects methods) in order to realize animations, but my question is very simple : i'm sure it's possible, but can you tell me (or help me) how should i combine several animations on a shape ? For example, rotating and translating a sphere.
When i'm doing :

```
three.sphere.rotation.y += 0.1;
three.sphere.translateZ += 1;
```

the sphere rotates but the translation vector is also rotating, so the translation has no effect.
I know a bit openGL and i already have used glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix functions, so do them exist in this framework ?
Cheers

Comment: I suggest you to use http://jsfiddle.net/ to show us your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each three.js [object3D](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D) has a `position`, `rotation` and `scale`; the rotation (always  relative to its origin or "center") defines its own local axis coordinates (say, what the object sees as its own "front,up, right" directions) and when you call `translateZ`, the object is moved according to those local directions (not along the world -or parent- Z axis).  If you want the later, do `three.sphere.position.z += 1` instead.

Comment: Thx a lot, it was indeed a real bad mistake. You solved my problem :)

Comment: as of today (r68), the position, rotation and scale atrtibutes are immutable: https://plus.google.com/+RicardoCabello/posts/WTwRMQznX6y use: object1.position.copy( object2.position );

Comment: So instead of manipulating position attribute directly you can use Vector3 methods like add, sub, copy

Answer (score 2):

The order of transformation is important. You get a different result if you translate first and then rotate than if you rotate first and then translate. Of course with a sphere it will be hard to see the rotation.

Comment: i can see the sphere's rotation thanks to a specific material i put in it. But i tryed to change those order and it does not change anything, always the same problem :/ But i found out my mistake : just a wrong function spell :) thanks anyway !

Comment: This is not technically true - though you may get undesired results. The rotation is always applied before the transformation, regardless of the order you define them. The only way to change this is to nest objects such that: create mesh, transform mesh, nest mesh in Object3D, rotate object.

Answer (score 1):

the comment by "plyawn" is correct "The rotation is always applied before the transformation, regardless of the order you define them. The only way to change this is to nest objects such that: create mesh, transform mesh, nest mesh in Object3D, rotate object"

```
obj1 = ...
const obbj2 = new THREE.Object3D();
obj2.add(obj1)
obj2.rotation.x = ... 
obj2.position.set(...)
return obj2
```